# How to create your own animations in 2D unity? I mean, for example, Change of color, position and the like?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to create your own animations in 2D unity? I mean, for example, Change of color, position and the like?

My point is how to make an animation that would, for example, change the color of the character to red, then normal, and so on - it could be an animation taking damage. So how do you do something like this? Yes, from total scratch!

Comment: You should be able to change any property(include sprite color) in the animation editor/timeline.

Comment: This is covered in pretty much any Unity3d animation tutorial. Please try to do some research before askign a question on stack

Answer (score 1):

Unity allows you to create an animator controller for any sprite. From there, you should able to create different animation clip via the animation window. In each animation clip, there are different properties you can manipulate either the sprite color, position.. etc. To make it work I'll suggest to push record in the the animation window to create your animation clip. From there, you can fix the animation transition between clips via animator window to your liking. It works similar in 3D but with gameObject.